# How to perform case insensitive searches using Quarkus Panache with Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, quarkus-panache

How to perform case insensitive searches using Quarkus Panache with Mongo?

I read online there is a lower() function that can be used but it doesn't work as then it returns all records.  Or perhaps the online suggestion did not use the correct syntax?

Where is the definitive guide/manual for Quarkus Panache with Mongo to do things like case insensitive searches, LIKE searches, etc.